# On Change en Select con Vue

Tags: vue.js

Espero alguien me pueda orientar con mi problema.

Tengo un Select y mi intención es que cuando cambie a cierto valor, una casilla de texto se habilite o desabilite según sea el caso.

**¿Cómo lo puedo hacer con Vuejs ?**

*Antes lo hacia con Jquery
y era así:* 
*(En este ejemplo cuando seleccionas del Select al país Mexico se habilitan los inputs de los contrario se vuelven a desabilitar)*

```js
$(document).ready( function(){

//Al cargar la página se debilitan los inputs
$('#estado').attr('disabled', true);
$('#ciudad').attr('disabled', true);

//Sí el usuario selecciona el país Mexico se habilitan los inputs
$('#pais').on('change', function(){
        var conf = $('#pais').val();
        if (conf === "México") {
            $('#estado').removeAttr('disabled');
            $('#ciudad').removeAttr('disabled');
        }else {
            $('#estado').attr('disabled', true);
            $('#ciudad').attr('disabled', true);
            $('#estado').val('');
            $('#ciudad').val('');
        }
});

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container pt-5">

<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    <select name="pais" id="pais" class="form-control" required>
      <option value="" selected>Seleccione...</option>
      <option value="México">México</option>
      <option value="España">España</option>
      <option value="Colombia">Colombia</option>
      <option value="Venezuela">Venezuela</option>
      <option value="Perú">Perú</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-3">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Estado:</label>
    <input type="text" name="estado" id="estado" class="form-control">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-3">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Ciudad:</label>
    <input type="text" name="ciudad" id="ciudad" class="form-control">
  </div>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Si nos compartes el codigo del componente donde tienes el select podremos ayudarte más facilmente.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En vue, seria exactamente lo mismo. Asignas a tu select que ejecute una funcion cuando ocurra el evento onChange, y luego habilitas o deshabilitas una propiedad de tu data para que apague o prenda el textbox

```
<select name="pais" id="pais" class="form-control" @change="onChange()" required>
```

Y tu textbox deberia tener

```
<input type="text" name="ciudad" id="ciudad" :disabled="habilitado == 1" class="form-control">
```

Y en tu control deberias tener:

```
data: {
    habilitado : 0
},
methods: {
    onChange() {
        if (lo que necesites) {
            this.habilitado = 1
        } else {
            this.habilitado = 0
        }
    }
}
```

Ademas, tu select tambien deberia estar bindeado a una propiedad del data, para poder rescatar el valor que tomo.

Comment: Como obtengo el valor selecionado?

Comment: @mariovials de que? si tenes otra pregunta, hacela..